# How to display HTML string in flutter?

Tags: html, flutter

I want to show html string as table like this ;
[image]

but when I use the html package in flutter , it couldn't display ,

this is what I see in flutter ;

[image]

here is the string that I want to display =>

```
"<table id='ParametersTable' style='width:100%'><thead><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><label class='col-form-label'>Employee</label></td><td colspan='8' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 66.66666666666666%'>1003 - Abdulsamed Demirtop</td></tr></thead><tbody class='parambody'><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><input id='1030' name ='1030' value='1030' hidden /><label class='col-form-label'>Id</label></td><td colspan='7' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 58.333333333333336%'>4</td><td colspan='1' style='padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; width: 8.333333333333332%'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><input id='1032' name ='1032' value='1032' hidden /><label class='col-form-label'>FromDate</label></td><td colspan='7' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 58.333333333333336%'>25/Dec/2022 11:30 AM</td><td colspan='1' style='padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; width: 8.333333333333332%'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><input id='1033' name ='1033' value='1033' hidden /><label class='col-form-label'>EndDate</label></td><td colspan='7' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 58.333333333333336%'>28/Dec/2022 11:30 PM</td><td colspan='1' style='padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; width: 8.333333333333332%'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><input id='1034' name ='1034' value='1034' hidden /><label class='col-form-label'>Country</label></td><td colspan='7' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 58.333333333333336%'>Turkiye</td><td colspan='1' style='padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; width: 8.333333333333332%'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><input id='1035' name ='1035' value='1035' hidden /><label class='col-form-label'>City</label></td><td colspan='7' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 58.333333333333336%'>Ankara</td><td colspan='1' style='padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; width: 8.333333333333332%'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><input id='1036' name ='1036' value='1036' hidden /><label class='col-form-label'>Type</label></td><td colspan='7' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 58.333333333333336%'>Flight</td><td colspan='1' style='padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; width: 8.333333333333332%'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%'><input id='1037' name ='1037' value='1037' hidden /><label class='col-form-label'>Purpose</label></td><td colspan='7' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 58.333333333333336%'>Meeting</td><td colspan='1' style='padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; width: 8.333333333333332%'></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan='4' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 33.33333333333333%; white-space: nowrap'><label class='col-form-label'>Notes</label></td><td colspan='8' style='padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; width: 66.66666666666666%'><input id='notes' name='notes' autocomplete='off' style='width: 100%' class='form-control' /></td></tr></tfoot></table>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)

for example:

```
                 Html(
                    data: 'Replace your content here',
                    style: <String, Style>{
                       //TODO put here your style 
                    },
                  )
```

Comment: I use this way but I didn't display as table, just saw like this => https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze60n.jpg

Comment: Check this, it might help: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#table

Comment: it couldn't work